Is there any limit to asexual reproduction?
As far as I know, DNA degrades with age.  How does this combine with asexual reproduction?
Let's say I have an individual of a plant, and reproduce it asexually.  Once it dies, I reproduce its asexually-reproduced children (or clones, should I say?).  And I (and my descendents) follow that technique throughout centuries.
I assume that since the DNA comes from the very first individual, and it must have degraded over time, at some point it will not be viable to reproduce anymore.
Am I right in that assumption?  For how long can species reproduce asexually without significant degradation?  I guess it also depends on the complexity of the species.

DNA stored in a vial degrades with age as does any biological material, DNA in a living organsim does not.

@John I don't know much about this, so I may very well be wrong, but for a long time I've seen in news and documentaries that DNA gets damaged with age.  For example, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7846274/.  Does it not get damaged under normal conditions then?

basically any chemical can breakdown with time, biological systems are constantly repairing and/or replacing the chemicals.

So, DNA can fully self-repair to the point that there's no significant degradation over millenniums and tens/hundreds/thousands of generations of asexual reproduction of an individual?

correct, now of course mutations will occur but that is completely diffrent than chemical degridation.

I don't really know a lot about DNA. But I think you meant that the ends of the DNA is "breaking of" while copying it. This is because the protein that is reproducing the DNA needs some time to work rightly. These ends are build by a completely random order of the bases.(the information is saved by the order of them)
At some point important information is breaking of the DNA, that is why we get older.
With every generation somehow these ends somehow have to reset. I have no clue how that is working.
Please correct me if I am wrong. All the information I got from the biology class, so important stuff could be missing. (Or isn't even right)
Anyway I hope I could help you.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Cc: @John  Do you have any comments?
